# Expand combined argument flags in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, arguments

Is there a way to rewrite a (Bash) script's arguments such that:

1. The argument string `-ab arg2` becomes `-a -b arg2`, and
2. `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, evaluate to `-a`, `-b`, `arg2`, respectively?

The format I'm using is `./my-script first_flag all other optional args`, where **first_flag** is used by **my-script**, and all other arguments (if any) are passed to **another-script**.

my-script:

```
#!/bin/bash

first_flag="$1"
shift 1

case "$first_flag" in
    "-a") ./another-script command1 $@ ;;
    "-z") ./another-script command2 $@ ;;
    *) echo "unknown flag"; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Comment: What you request for is the default behavior.

Comment: @Xaqron Not default, but the *conventional* interpretation of most libraries for parsing options. `bash` itself has no notion of such a convention.

Comment: @chepner Wouldn't `getopts` with `ab:` behave exactly like that?

Comment: `getopt -oab: -- "-ab" "arg2"` will output `-a -b arg2 --`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. `getopts` itself may be built-in, but it's still closer to a library than anything inherent to the language.

Comment: See https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/getopt-parse.bash